# Hive Metastore service having lot of threads of type, JMX server connection timeout

Tags: java, jmx, java-threads, hive-metastore

I have a deployment of HMS v2.0.1 on k8s with 20 replicas. Over the time, it becomes unresponsive.

- CPU usage keeps on increasing. With it, increase in CPU throttling also.
- JVMs are configured with 13 GB.
- Some of the pods show unusually high number of threads like ~700-800.
  Majority of threads are of category `JMX server connection timeout`

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
- locked <0x0000000544732110> (a [I)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

- Another impact is that app stops sending the JMX metrics after some time.

I am not able to figure out the exact issue here. Looking for any tip/guidance from the community.

Comment: You need to provide more information in order to diagnose/replicate however, I can suggest... checking JMX server config, analysing resource allocation, reviewing HMS logs, scaling and monitoring the deployment.